# Display blog posts on any page on wordpress query is not working

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php // 
    $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('showposts=3' . '&paged='.$paged);
    ?>
      <ul class="column-three">
          <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()){ the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails'); } else {echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/b.jpg'. '"/>'; }?>
      <span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
      <span class="incrypt"><?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,30); ?></span>
      <span class="read-more">Read More</span>
          </a>
        </li>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
     </ul>
     <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

before code above is working until wordpress updates, my problem is the number of post display must be 3 post only but it display more than 3 is there any hope or is there something messing in my code above

Answer (score 2):

Well, the `showposts` parameter is replaced with `posts_per_page`. So try with

`$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=3' . '&paged='.$paged);`

You could use:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3, 
    'paged' => $paged, 
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Yes showposts is deprecated. It is posts_per_page now.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is working for me and I have make page-test.php and get posts in that page and "**showposts**" working for me still use "**posts_per_page**" as mentioned by @jogesh_pi comment and also try below code that will also get posts by **get_posts** function.

```
  $post_list = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'numberposts' => 3,
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order',
        'sort_order' => 'asc'
   ) );

?>
<ul class="column-three">
<?php  foreach ( $post_list as $post ) {  ?>
<li>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="post-<?php $post->ID; ?>">
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)){  $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"/>
<?php
} else {echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/b.jpg'. '"/>'; }?>
<span class="title"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></span>
<span class="incrypt"><?php  $excerpt = $post->post_excerpt; echo substr( $excerpt , 0, 30);?></span>
<span class="read-more">Read More</span>
</a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try With this.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1'
    ); 

    $query = new WP_Query ($args );             
    while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```